# Приостановление/возобновление выполнения задачи(цикла) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

Есть код, в котором заполняется прогрессбар, дойдя до предела двигается назад.

```
 private async void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 500; ++i)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5);
            label.Content = i.ToString();
            pg1.Value = i;
        }

        if (pg1.Value == 500)
        {
            for (i = 500; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5);
                label.Content = i.ToString();
                pg1.Value = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

В общем как создать эмуляцию остановки понятно, например так:

```
Task.Delay(5000000)
```

Так вот, как используя второй обработчик **приостановить!!**, а не **завершить** выполнение цикла и соответственно выполнение задачи(заполнение прогрессбара), затем возобновить его если это необходимо, то есть с остановкой нету проблем, но как потом запустить цикл с текущего значения, чтобы отсчет продолжался после приостановки задачи(цикла).

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы не работаете через привязки. Просто создайте свойство `Current` и меняете его же в цикле. В следующий раз просто стартуете с него.

Comment: Или вам нужно что-то вроде этого? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613444/a-pattern-to-pause-resume-an-async-task